# pandas.DataFrame.to_csv Invalid argument for only a specific file name on a specific computer

Tags: python, pandas

```
df.to_csv(general_info.data_folder() + '\\Back Up Data\\Week of 2022-06-19.csv')
```

The error is:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'O:\\\\Operations\\Data\\Back Up Data\\Week of 2022-06-19.csv'
```

general_info_datafolder() returns a path.
If I remove the dashes, or move dashes, it works:

```
"Week of 2022-06 19"
"Week-of 2022-06-19"
"Week-of 2022 06-19"
"Week-of 2022 06 19"
"Week of 2022 06 19"
```

There isn't already a file in that folder with the same name. Also, it works on someone else's computer. Why does only my computer not take only that one file name?

Comment: Is this a network path? If so you would probably need to put the fully qualified name. Additionally, you have a mix of single \ as well as \\. To help prevent this error you can simply right r'O:\Operations\Data\Back Up Data\...so forth and so on

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You just try by importing pathlib `from pathlib import Path` next try to append the data in csv by `df.to_csv(Path(general_info.data_folder() + '\Back Up Data\Week of 2022-06-19.csv'))`. If this is not work, make sure you had give the right path and also make sure the folder is available.